# Inability to build debug libraries on Windows for OpenXLSX using cmake

Tags: cmake, openxlsx

While the OpenXLSX homepage gives instructions on how to build Release libraries for Windows from source, [see [here](https://github.com/troldal/OpenXLSX)] I am having difficulty following parallel steps to build Debug libraries.

First, I provide:

`cmake --build . --target OpenXLSX --config Debug`

This completes fine with the last message being:

`OpenXLSX.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Tryer\Downloads\OpenXLSX-master\OpenXLSX-master\OpenXLSX\build\Debug\OpenXLSXd.lib`

Then, I give the custom prefix command to complete the process thus:

`cmake --install . --prefix "C:\Users\Tryer\OpenXLSX\windows\Debug"`

to install the library in the specified folder. However, this fails with the final error message being:

```
  CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:79 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/Tryer/Downloads/OpenXLSX-master/OpenXLSX-master/OpenXLSX/build/Release/OpenXLSX.lib":
  File exists.
```

Note the folder unnecessarily being referred to is `build/Release/`  which does not exist given that I am building with `Debug` option.

Line 79 (added below in braces) refers to the line in the following block of code in `cmake_install.cmake` file:

```
if(CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT STREQUAL "lib" OR NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT)
  if(CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME MATCHES "^([Dd][Ee][Bb][Uu][Gg])$")
    file(INSTALL DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib" TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY FILES "C:/Users/Tryer/Downloads/OpenXLSX-master/OpenXLSX-master/OpenXLSX/build/Debug/OpenXLSXd.lib")
  elseif(CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME MATCHES "^([Rr][Ee][Ll][Ee][Aa][Ss][Ee])$")
   (line79) file(INSTALL DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib" TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY FILES "C:/Users/Tryer/Downloads/OpenXLSX-master/OpenXLSX-master/OpenXLSX/build/Release/OpenXLSX.lib")
  elseif(CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME MATCHES "^([Mm][Ii][Nn][Ss][Ii][Zz][Ee][Rr][Ee][Ll])$")
    file(INSTALL DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib" TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY FILES "C:/Users/Tryer/Downloads/OpenXLSX-master/OpenXLSX-master/OpenXLSX/build/MinSizeRel/OpenXLSX.lib")
  elseif(CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME MATCHES "^([Rr][Ee][Ll][Ww][Ii][Tt][Hh][Dd][Ee][Bb][Ii][Nn][Ff][Oo])$")
    file(INSTALL DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib" TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY FILES "C:/Users/Tryer/Downloads/OpenXLSX-master/OpenXLSX-master/OpenXLSX/build/RelWithDebInfo/OpenXLSX.lib")
  endif()
endif()
```

How can one fix this to obtain debug libraries that can be loaded so that I can step through my code in Debug mode in an IDE?